# Golang PostgreSQL Error: "getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found."

Tags: postgresql, go

I am having an issue with Go and performing standard operations on my PostgreSQL database.

I first started coding with GORM, and was getting the following error message while connecting:

> dial tcp: lookup tcp/fullstack_api: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found.

After switching to the standard `"database/sql"` package with the `_ "github.com/lib/pq"` postgreSQL dialect, connecting was no longer throwing this error. However, now I get this error when trying to perform any query on the connected database, which I assume GORM was doing initially.

The following code causes this error on my system:

```
// Connect initiates a DB connection.
func (dbConn *PostgresConnection) Connect() error {
    handle, connErr := sql.Open("postgres", dbConn.getConnectionString())
    if connErr != nil { // Does NOT cause an error
        return connErr 
    }
    if pingErr := handle.Ping(); pingErr != nil { // Causes the above error
        return pingErr
    }
    dbConn.handle = handle
    return nil
}
```

I have checked that the PostgreSQL service is running, and the database exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing this question, I checked my connection string / env variables again.

I realized that I had a stupid copy/paste error from the day before that I hadn't validated:

> Connection string: `host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 port=new_database user=db_user password=XXXXXX`

As you can see, there is an additional `port` variable that should have been the `dbname`. After fixing this issue, everything worked as expected.

> Connection string: `host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=new_database user=db_user password=XXXXXX`

**TLDR:** Always re-validate every piece of your connection information when getting this (cryptic) error!

Comment: Agreed. Also to debug place logs/printf statement's, it will be easier to check.